# how to avoid treeview negative node number problem

Tags: vb6, treeview

I am binding a database table data to treeview.
In documntation it is mentioned nodes count property as integer value which is signed 2 byte.
so if the nodes exceeds this range, nodes count is becoming negative.
Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a [documented](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182231) bug. Fortunately, no one ever encounters it in the real world because it's completely nonsensical for a single TreeView control to ever need to display more than 32,767 nodes.

As mentioned in the linked knowledge base article, the best workaround is to maintain less nodes in your `TreeView` control. Consider splitting the data up between multiple TreeViews, or using a different control that is better suited for such incredibly large quantities of data.

If you absolutely must use a `TreeView`, Microsoft recommends that you keep the following in mind:

- Performance will become extremely slow as you add more and more nodes.
- Do not add more than 65535 nodes. (That's the limit imposed by the native control, which uses an unsigned integer to store the node count.)
- Use the [`SendMessage` API function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950.aspx) to obtain the true node count. Alternately, you can use a module- or public-level variable to keep track of how many nodes are in the TreeView. Each time you add or remove a node, increment or decrement the variable by one. This is necessary if you need to determine the count of nodes because the `Count` property of the `Nodes` collection will not return the correct value.
- Don't rely on the `Index` property of a node object. For example, the `Index` property is 32767 for node 32767 but is -32768 for node 32768.
- You can still refer to a node by using its `Key` or by passing a number to the `Nodes` collection.
  For example:

  ```
  TreeView1.Nodes(40000) refers to node 40000.
  ```

Comment: My treeview (the standard one in Mscomctl) hosts a million nodes and performs quite well. The index problem is nasty though.